# Resource file is missing with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I'm working on a GWT project with maven. Since I want to keep my workspace organized I'm putting all my resources on src/main/resources instead of src/main/java. The problem is that eclipse gives an compile error saying that the file is missing. On the other hand if I insist in proceding the project compiles and works properly (it does find supposedly missing resources). How can I correct this?

Thank you.

Comment: Adding the `resources` folder as a source folder usually does the trick.

Comment: @Anders Isn't that the default when using maven with eclipse?

Comment: @DirkLachowski could be, it's been a while with Eclipse - I'm on Intellij for GWT projects these days...

Comment: Remove the project from Eclipse and afterwards delete the Eclipse specific files (.settings, .classpath, .project) and import the project from scratch.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup The resources folder is a source folder already.

Comment: @khmarbaise Your solution worked. If you put it on an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the project from Eclipse and afterwards delete the Eclipse specific files (.settings, .classpath, .project) and import the project from scratch. The problem is based on the thing that the life-cycle is started from scratch in case of importing it. If a project is already important some parts seemed to be not executed.